# please help getting java.lang.nullpointerexception while running the program

Tags: java, windows, cmd

help me out with this code,i am getting run time exception error java.lang.nullpointerexception plz help me solving this and how to access any file on desktop using java program ,
                           like i want to access any image or text file on desktop or in any other folde what code should i write .FYI i am noob.

```
import java.io.*;
class jarvis
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
String i=null,j=null,k=null,l=null,m=null,n=null,o=null,a=null,q=null;
try
{
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(i.equals("jarvis you there?"))
{
i=br.readLine();

System.out.println("at your service sir");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(j.equals("run command prompt"))
{
j=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(k.equals("run notepad"))
{
k=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("notepd.exe");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(l.equals("run paint"))
{
l=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("mspaint.exe");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(m.equals("open facebook"))
{
m=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start www.facebook.com");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(n.equals("open google"))
{
n=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start www.google.com");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(o.equals("open youtube"))
{
o=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start www.youtube.com");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(a.equals("open yahoo"))
{
a=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start www.yahoo.com");
}
System.out.println("Command me: ");
if(q.equals("open omegle"))
{
q=br.readLine();
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p=r.exec("cmd.exe /c start www.omegle.com");
}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String i=null,j=null,k=null,l=null,m=null,n=null,o=null,a=null,q=null;
try
{
     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     System.out.println("Command me: ");
     if(i.equals("jarvis you there?"))
         ...
```

The variable `i` is `null` but you try to dereference it. Perform

```
i=br.readLine();
```

before comparing its value.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `i` without initializing it

```
String i=null
if(i.equals("jarvis you there?"))
  ^^^^
Here there is NPE
```

Best you can do is to put constant on left side of equals

```
if("jarvis you there?".equals(i))
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is executed in the order you write it. If you want to compare user input to some value inside an `if` you have to read it before you compare it:

```
System.out.println("Command me: ");
i = br.readLine();
if(i.equals("jarvis you there?"))
{
    System.out.println("at your service sir");
}
```

That could still give you a null pointer exception since `readLine()` can return null. The easiest way to prevent that here is to switch the sides of the `equals`. Literal strings are objects so they have methods like `equals` but they can't be null.

```
if("jarvis you there?".equals(i))
```

The next thing you will find is that your programs reads a line and checks if it is the first command only, read the next line and check if it is the second command and so on. To get the `"run paint"` command you have to enter it as the 4th line.

You should compare the very same line to every possible command. For example by using `if .. else if ... else if ... else`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
for (;;) {
    System.out.println("Command me: ");
    String line = br.readLine();
    if ("foo".equals(line)) {
        // do foo
    } else if ("bar".equals(line)) {
        // do bar
    } else if ("baz".equals(line)) {
        // do baz
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unknown Command. Bye.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Or in Java 7 with `switch`

```
    switch (line) {
        case "foo":
            // do foo
            break;
        case "bar":
            // do foo
            break;
        //...
        default: 
            // } else {
            break;
    }
```

Or in fancy object oriented style: http://ideone.com/d6pf7T